# Is there some way with dapper object in object to load in sfdatagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion, .net-6.0

I am using Dapper and when i execute query and load to SfDataGrid only show results from first table.

Model:

```
public class Users
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Roles role { get; set; }
}

public class Roles
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

So when i do like

```
sfDataGrid1.DataSource = results;
```

Its only show user id, name, email without role name.

Query:

```
select a.*, b.name from users a inner join roles b on users.roleID = roles.id.

Tables users: id, name, email, roleID.

Table roles: id, name.
```

EDIT:

```
public List<Users> GetUsers() { 
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("db2021"))) { var sql = @"SELECT A.*, B.* FROM users A INNER JOIN Roles B on B.id = A.roleID"; 
    var result = connection.Query<Users>(sql, (a, b) => { a.role = b; return a; }).ToList(); return result; } 
    }

List<Users> users = new List<Users>(); 
users = GetUsers(); 
sfDataGrid1.DataSource = users;
```

Comment: Please show the exact code around the call to the Dapper Query call.

Comment: I edit, sorry for this my bad, its my first post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have a class Roles like this one

```
public class Roles
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}

}
```

Then your query should be

```
public List<Users> GetUsers() { 
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("db2021"))) { 
        var sql = @"SELECT A.*, B.* FROM users A INNER JOIN Roles B on B.id = A.roleID"; 
        var result = connection.Query<Users,Roles,Users>(sql, (a, b) => 
        { 
             a.role = b; 
             return a; 
        }).ToList(); 
        return result; 
   } 
}


List<Users> users = GetUsers(); 
sfDataGrid1.DataSource = users;
```

In other words you need to tell Dapper what is the class that represent the B.* data and what is the return value from the lambda.

If you instead want a single class that has both the user and just the role name data then you need to define this particular class as

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int roleid {get;set;}
    public string rolename {get;set;}
}
```

And the query should change to retrieve the data in this way

```
public List<Users> GetUsers() 
{ 
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(....))
    { 
        var sql = @"SELECT A.*, B.name as rolename 
                    FROM users A INNER JOIN Roles B 
                                 ON B.id = A.roleID"; 
        var result = connection.Query<UsersViewModel>(sql).ToList(); 
        return result; 
   } 
}
```

Notice how this has no more a one-to-one mapping to the database fields hence we have a ViewModel kind of class and we name it appropriately to avoid confusion.

Also with dapper it is important to have the same name for properties and columns extracted by the query; so the *name* column in the role table appears as *rolename* in the query. This will allow dapper to build the UserViewModel class instances from the query's resultset.

Comment: Thanks, i can now show for users what is the name of role on users.role.name but when i try to sfDataGrid1.DataSource users; it show all columns from Users model without Roles. How to add or what i need to do to show my role name column in datagrid also.

Comment: I don't know that grid control. It all depends if it is capable to show a sublist. The important thing is to check if the returned list structure contains both the user and role data separated in their own classes. If you instead want a single class/structure with both the user and roles data then you need to define this class and make changes to your query as well. I will show a possible implementation

Comment: I checked returned list structure it has all users columns and object Roles and inside  object Roles have id and name.

Comment: You really helped me a lot. Thanks !